# Telerik MVC Grid insert button text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

How can the text be changed for the insert command button on a Telerik MVC Grid.

I am using Master-Detail with 2 sub-levels and I want to personalize each level individually. The only way I know now is to change all the insert buttons from jQuery.

I am thinking that the solution should be something with custom commands and an action that emulates the insert functionality.

**Solution from Chrissav**:

```
.ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().HtmlAttributes( new { id = "addLvl1" }))
.ClientEvents(e => e.OnLoad("changeText")
```

Function

```
 function changeText() {
         $('[id=addLvl1]').text('Insert Level 1');
         $('[id=addLvl2]').text('Insert Level 2');
         $("[id=addLvl3]").text('Insert Level 3');
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post explains it can only be done from localization:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/grid-insert-button-text.aspx

I've also just done this using Jquery.

In the grid:

```
.ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().HtmlAttributes( new { id = "myID" }))
.ClientEvents(e => e
            .OnLoad("changeText")
```

jq:

```
function changeText() {
        $('#myID').text('change the text here');
    }
```

You mention trying custom commands so you can try something like this

```
.ToolBar(commands => commands.Custom() .Text("Insert Text") .Action("Action", "Controller")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chrissav. Solutions 1 and 3 don't really work for my problem, but the second was bang on. My grid is Master-Detail so changing the localization would change it for all the Insert buttons. Also, I'm using Ajax so I can't call the .Action("Action", "Controller") because it would open a new view.